# What is the best way to track / record the current programming project u work on

Tags: python, coding-style, project-management, jira, issue-tracking

I have been in this problem for long time and i want to know how its done in real / big companies project.

Suppose i have the project to build a website. now i divide the project into sub tasks and do it.

But u know that suppose i have `task1` in hand like export the `page to pdf`. Now i spend 3 days to do that , came accross various problems , many stack overflow questions and in the end i solve it.

Now 4 months after someone told me that there is some error in the code.

Now by that i comepletely forgot about(60%) how i did it and why i do this way. I document the code but i can't write the whole story of that in the code.

Then i have to spend much time on code to find what was the problem so that i added this line etc.

I want to know that is there any way that i can log steps in completeing the project.
So that i can see how i end up with code , what erros i got , what questions i asked on So and etc.

How people do it in real time. Which software to use.

I know in our project management softaware called `JIRA` we have tasks  but that does not cover **what steps i took to solve that tasks**.

what is the besy way so that when i look backt at my 2 year old project , i know how i solve particular task

Comment: Adding comments would be a start.

Comment: @Blender I add commnets in code. But sometimes after doing research from internet i endup with some code. and then what would be drawbacks of doing it usual way and all that stuff. i can't add whole paragraphs in there. And also that does not tell the order in which i solved the issue. i may end up with 1000 lines of code an then can't figure out which code i wrote first. i can find that in source control but that will not be more efficeint. i want something like tasks then subtasks then relate tasks with my commits , add SO questions , etc. and in the end i can see how i completed the issue

Comment: Good comments are often hard to do.  You might want to check out The art of Readable Code: http://www.amazon.com/dp/0596802293 for some good hints on code and comment practices that make life easier down the road.  The basic rule is pretty simple: dont describe the code, record the things you think you'll need to know when you look at it in a year and don't remember what you were thinking

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using JIRA consider integrating it with your SCM.

When committing your changes to SCM refer to your JIRA issue number in comments. Like the following:

```
PORTAL-778 fixed the alignment issue with PDF exports
```

JIRA periodically connects to your SCM and parses the comments. You can easily find out changes made for a particular issue.

Please see the following link for more information

[Integrating JIRA with Subversion](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Integrating+JIRA+with+Subversion)

Answer (score 0):

Every time you revisit code, make a list of the information you are not finding. Then the next time you create code, make sure that information is present. It can be in comments, Wiki, bugs or even text notes in a separate file. Make the notes useful for other people, so private notebooks aren't a good idea except for personal notes.